What does "trap entry point" means?
From Chapter 2 (The Popek/Goldberg Theorem) in Hardware and Software Support for Virtualization - Synthesis Lectures on Computer Architecture,

... consider what an operating system for such an architecture would
look like (in the absence of a VMM).
The kernel would run in supervisor mode (M = s), and applications
would always run in user mode (M = u).
During initialization, the kernel first sets the trap entry point:
MEM[0]  (M:s,B:0,L:SZ,PC:trap_en).
The kernel would allocate a contiguous range of physical memory for
each application.
To launch or resume an application stored in physical memory at
[B,B+L[ and currently executing instruction P C, the operating system
would simply load PSW (M:u,L,C,PC).
At the trap entry point (P C =trap_en), the kernel would first decode
the instruction stored at MEM1.PC to determine the cause of the
trap, and then take appropriate action.
Although idealized, notably because of the lack of registers, this
architectural model is not fundamentally different from the ones that
we are all familiar with today. ...

What does "trap entry point" mentioned above mean in the context? Does it mean the address of the memory location where the old PSW is saved when a trap occurs as stated in the original Popek and Goldberg paper where MEM[0] or E[0] is used for that purpose?
The Popek and Goldberg paper has this description of the traps:

Traps
We continue with the model of the third generation machine by defining the action of a trap. An instruction i is said to trap if i(E1,M1,P1,R1) = (E2,M2,P2,R2) where
E2[j] = E1[j], for0 <j < q,
E2[0] = (M1,P1,R1)
(M2, P2, R2) = E11.
Hence, when an instruction traps, storage is left unchanged, except for location zero in which is put the PSW that was in effect just before the instruction trapped. The PSW to be in effect after the instruction trapped is taken from location one. In the software of most third generation machines, one expects that M2 = s and R2 = (0,q-1).
Intuitively, a trap automatically saves the current state of the machine and passes control of a prespecified routine by changing the processor mode, the relocation bounds register, and the program counter to the values specified in E11. Our definition could be relaxed to include cases in which the trap does not block the instruction but rather gains control immediately afterward or even some number of instructions later, providing that the state of the machine is stored in such a way as to be reversible to the point at which the instruction causing the trap was about to be executed.

(Note that nomentclature is bit different between the two texts.)

Is there a valid reason this question gets downvoted? Is there some other StackExchange site better suited for this type of question?

The trap entry point is the memory address that you branch to when a trap occurs.

Does it mean the address of the memory location where the old PSW is saved when a trap occurs

No.  It is the value that is loaded into the PC when the trap occurs.

(I'm not going to give you a citations taken from the sources you are using.  The above just explains this from the perspective of real hardware ... on the assumption that Popek & Goldberg's model is intended to be based on how real hardware behaves.)

So that trap mechanism includes saving old PSW to a memory address different from MEM[0] to avoid overwriting the trap entry?

I don't know.  I presume so.  I haven't analyzed that book in detail.

But, if PSW.PC at MEM[0] is loaded into the processor when a trap occurs then the old PSW.PC will be lost before the trap handler can save it. Furthermore, the same source on the same page explicitly states "The trap architecture has provisions to first save the content of the PSW to a well-known
location in memory (MEM[0]), and then load into the PSW the values from another well-known location in memory (MEM[1])."   Can you explain this seeming conflict of using MEM[0], please?

No I can't.  Possibly what the book is saying is incomplete or inaccurate.  Or maybe it is explained by the context.  (It looks you have an excerpt of a single chapter there.  What does the rest of the book say?  I didn't pay the EU 29.95 to read a single book chapter.)  I suggest you contact the authors and ask them to explain this to you.

I've updated the question post to include the link for the full book.
